# Linux: No fonts match '9x15' when starting emacs

Tags: linux, fonts, emacs

I get the message

No fonts match '9x15'

when trying to run emacs and a linux box.  I messed something up a while back, but I do not know how to fix this issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: I am having a similar problem on Emacs 21.4.1 on CentOS 5.5.  I tried to use Inconsolata-12 (silly me) and now emacs won't start without the -fn flag.  I can't find where Inconsolata-12 is specified in any of my configuration files, like .emacs. Help?

Comment: I can't remember if I resolved this or just kept using a work around.  I no longer use that server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed [Xming-fonts](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/files/) package and read [Xming fonts](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/fonts.php) page?

With X11, the fonts are from the server, in your case Xming running on a PC, not the system executing the client application (emacs running on the Linux is a X client).

This doesn't appear to be a Linux or emacs issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does emacs still run? if so run `M-x customize-group basic-faces` - change the settings for default face, and save for future sessions.

If not, run "emacs -q" (this suppresses loading your init file) and then customize your default face.

Comment: emacs does not run after returning the 'No font match' message.  emacs -q also returns 'No font match'.  The problem is with the X window and I'm using Xming.

If I start a new putty session without setting the display emacs works fine.

Comment: Please Add Xming note to original question, to improve others answers.

Comment: use the -fn flag to select a font that exists: "emacs -fn fixed" should work, for example.

Comment: also, you can set your default font from "emacs -nw" (which is the equivalent of running emacs without the display set).

Comment: also, as mctylr mentions - if the problem is a missing font, that is a problem with the server on which the app is displayed (in your case Xming under Windows) not the Linux client.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on CentOS (not via Xming). There are no references to the problematic font (Inconsolata-12) in my .emacs file. Where else can I look to fix this configuration?